# Somar subitems entre grupos com linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, expressões-lambda, linq-to-sql

Como posso realizar cálculos entre subitems de uma consulta com group by no linq? Segue exemplo:

**Consulta Linq**

```html
var listPlanoDeContas = (from t in _planoDeContasRepository.GetAll()
                         orderby t.Month ascending
                         group t by t.DfpChartOfAccounts into dfpGroup
                         select dfpGroup).ToList();
```

Para ilustrar, essa consulta me retorna algo do tipo:

```html
Plano de Contas      |    Mês 1    |    Mês 2     |    Mês 3    | ...

Receitas Totais           10000,00        13000,00      8000,00
Deduções                    878,00         1020,00       780,00
Custos                     1345,00         1478,00       850,00
Despesas                   3789,00         4342,00      1678,00
______________________________________________________________________
Saldo de Caixa                ?               ?             ?
```

Eu preciso encontrar o **saldo de caixa**.
Então eu gostaria de uma ajuda para calcular via Linq ou Lambda os valores entre cada item do plano de contas por mês. Ou seja:

Receita Total do Mês 1 - Deduções do Mês 1 - Custos do Mês 1 - Despesas do Mês 1

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já recebe a tabela exatamente como está no seu exemplo? Se for isso não seria só criar uma classe para armazenar o total de cada mês? Vou criar uma resposta baseada nisso e vc vê se atende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```html
//Fiz uma consulta geral no DB e agrupei por mês
var qry = _planoDeContasRepository.GetAll()
  .GroupBy(x => x.Month).ToList();

//Pecorre a consulta aplicando o filtro e realizando o cálculo
foreach(var i in qry)
{
    var valorReceita = i.Where(x => x.Categoria.Equals("Receita")).Select(x => x.Valor).ToList();
    decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(valorReceita[0]);
    
    var somaTotalPorMes = i.Sum(x => x.Valor);

    decimal saldo = Convert.ToDecimal(somaTotalPorMes) - valor;
}

//Retorno o saldo e....
```

Answer (score 1):

Note que no exemplo abaixo estou usando uma classe de exemplo e campos hipotéticos da sua classe.

Mas acredito que apenas o código abaixo atenda sua necessidade, se o seu retorno na `listPlanoDeContas` for oque você postou na pergunta.

```
SaldoCaixa =
new TotaisSaldoCaixa
{
    Total_Janeiro = listPlanoDeContas
        .Select(c => c.ReceitaJan - c.DeducoesJan - c.CustosJan - c.DespesasJan).SingleOrDefault(),

    Total_Fevereiro = listPlanoDeContas
        .Select(c => c.ReceitaFeb - c.DeducoesFeb - c.CustosFeb - c.DespesasFeb).SingleOrDefault(),

    Total_Marco = listPlanoDeContas
        .Select(c => c.ReceitaMar - c.DeducoesMar - c.CustosMar - c.DespesasMar).SingleOrDefault(),
    //Restante dos meses...
};
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo e atenção, mas na verdade vou eu fiz uma query com um GroupBy por mês somando os valores. Depois fiz um sub-query da consulta anterior com o where da categoria "Receitas" e fiz uma subtração. A resposta vou postar aqui